# How to Crop biggest rectangle and applying wrap transform

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

hi can anyone help me to debug my codes i'm working on cropping the biggest rectangle and applying transformation to it. I uploaded the picture so you can see it. im using python 2.7 on raspberry pi and opencv 3.3.0

[image]

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Use a blurring effect, to (hopefully) remove these high frequency 
#noises.

image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(im,(3,3),0)



#apply a canny edge-detector

edges = cv2.Canny(image_blurred,100,300,apertureSize = 3)



#finding the contours in the image

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)



#to find the biggest rectangle. For each contour cnt, first find the 
#convex hull, then use approaxPolyDP to simplify the contour as much as 
#possible.

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
simplified_cnt = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull,0.001*cv2.arcLength(hull,True),True)



#after finding (hopefully) the right quadrilateral, is transforming back 
#to a rectangle. For this you can use findHomography to come up with a 
#transformation matrix.

(H,mask) = cv2.findHomography(cnt.astype('single'),np.array([[[0., 0.]],[[2150., 0.]],[[2150., 2800.]],[[0.,2800.]]],dtype=np.single))



#for the final tranformation on crop image using warpPerspective

final_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image,H,(2150, 2800))

cv2.imshow("Show",final_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this is my code but i always getting and error like this.

[image]

this is the error i got

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crop.py", line 11, in 
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs, findContours returns three values, use as following:

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```